# Unity Share Button Implementation

Tags: android, button, unity-game-engine, share

I'm trying to implement the share feature as shown in this blog: http://www.daniel4d.com/blog/sharing-image-unity-android/

But when I tried to share it to Line on Android I got this error: (http://triodigitalagency.com/line-error.png).

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
//instantiate the class Intent
AndroidJavaClass intentClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.content.Intent");

//instantiate the object Intent
AndroidJavaObject intentObject = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent");

//call setAction setting ACTION_SEND as parameter
intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setAction", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("ACTION_SEND"));

//instantiate the class Uri
AndroidJavaClass uriClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.net.Uri");

//instantiate the object Uri with the parse of the url's file
AndroidJavaObject uriObject = uriClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("parse","file://"+pathName);

//call putExtra with the uri object of the file
intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("EXTRA_STREAM"), uriObject);

//set the type of file
intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setType", "image/png");

//instantiate the class UnityPlayer
AndroidJavaClass unity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");

//instantiate the object currentActivity
AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unity.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

//call the activity with our Intent
currentActivity.Call("startActivity", intentObject);
```

I've been pulling my hairs for two days to find a solution, any sort of hint would be greatly appreciated! (even if it means I need to try other methods in implementing this share feature).

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Do you Grant the Writing Access to External on Player settings? Try to do this if not, you image will not create! :D

From author of this code:
Grant the Writing Access to External (SDCard) in PlayerSettings, otherwise you won’t be able to share pictures.